# Angular not able to get full url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, url, url-routing

requirement: need to hit the url

```
localhost:4200/keyone=valueone&keytwo=value2109808329csdc0qwd&keythree=xyz@pqr.com
```

then capture:

```
[keyone=valueone, keytwo=value2109808329csdc0qwd, keythree=xyz@pqr.com];
```

When I am hitting the url using angular 5 its changing to

```
localhost:4200/keyone
```

I am not getting the full url. Its disappearing from the `=` .

Comment: try `localhost:4200/?keyone=valueone&keytwo`

Comment: copy paste in the browser. But y it's discarding after =. m not able to understand.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey tried . not working

Answer (score 1):

Added a path and attached the required info as an id.
ex.

```
localhost:4200/item?keyone=valueone&keytwo=value2109808329csdc0qwd&keythree=xyz@pqr.com
```

And got the url values in windows.location.url

```
/item?keyone=valueone&keytwo=value2109808329csdc0qwd&keythree=xyz@pqr.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The url looks fine and you should get into a url routed page which is mapped to this irl. As I guess there are no routing available to the url you are providing, its redirecting to a one it found

Normally in angular we catch url params in below way

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: ':keyone/:keytwo/:keythree',
  component: SomeComponent,
  resolve: {
    resolvedData: SomeResolverService,
  }
}
```

And then in your resolver or component you can get them by

```
// inject ActivatedRouteSnapshot
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
```

Then get the params

```
route.params.keyone, route.params.keytwo, route.params.keythree,
```

Comment: Route worked for me bro. Need not inject anything else.